# How to securely send the list of permissions and accesses to my web application?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, security, authorization, role-base-authorization

I have a web application where I want to obtain in a dynamic way the permissions and accesses of the role-based application, the API has its respective validations but I would like to know what are the best practices to implement this in the frontend without generating vulnerabilities.

Comment: that all depends on what your role base authorization pattern is, are you using a design pattern? or something custom?

Comment: @alilland It's custom, do you recommend something specific?, currently I was thinking about returning a list with their respective read and write permissions but that breaks the security.

Comment: when walking through a mine field, its best to follow someone. Having written my own custom one years ago and now supporting a large system that sits on top of it, i would be willing to spend weeks to pick out a more robust pattern today if i had the chance.